# Incorrect syntax near '<' in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

```
       String start_cd;
       String end_cd;
       int time_start_int;
       int time_end_int;
        opencon();

        SqlCommand res = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,Available,Type," + start_cd + "," + 
            end_cd + " FROM " + going + 
           " WHERE " + start_cd + "!=0 or " + end_cd + "!=0 and " + 
           time_start_int + " <= " + start_cd + " <= " + time_end_int + "", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda_res = new SqlDataAdapter(res);
        DataTable dt_res = new DataTable();
        sda_res.Fill(dt_res);

        listBox1.DataSource=dt_res;
        listBox1.DisplayMember="ID";

        listBox2.DataSource = dt_res;
        listBox2.DisplayMember = start_cd;
```

I want to get sql table column value `time_start_int` between `time_end_int`

I am getting error

> Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: Do not concatenate your strings, it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Convert the int ti string, then concatenate the strings.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot write `start <= column <= end` in a SQL query.

You need to do:

```
"...and start_cd >= " + time_start_int + " and " + start_cd + " <= " + time_end_int
```

But please do not concatenate your strings, it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection. Use SQL parameters.

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to say as I don't know your data.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get between two value query.
but your typed code not correct syntax in sql and not a C# problem.

```
 SELECT [ID]
      ,[Available]
      ,[Type]     
  FROM [dbo].[Going]
  where start_cd !=0 or end_cd!=0 and time_end_int <= start_cd <= time_start_int
```

Test this code:

```
    SELECT [ID]
      ,[Available]
      ,[Type]   FROM [dbo].[Going]
  where start_cd !=0 or end_cd!=0 and (time_end_int <= start_cd and  start_cd <= time_start_int)
```

I hope help you.